# How can I restrict a user's time spent on internet?

Tags: internet, parental-controls

I see related questions on how to restrict access to certain websites but that is not really what I want.  Here's my situation:

My baby sitter wants access to the internet but we we don't want her spending hours on the computer and neglecting our infant children.  Thus, I want to be able to restrict her surfing to 30 minutes a session, with sessions being at least 3 hours apart.  I do not care to restrict the content.  Does anyone know what is the best way to implement this?  Thanks.

Comment: Find another babysitter? :)

Comment: Haha, we did consider this but she's actually really good with the kids.

Comment: Not to state the obvious here, but if she's really that good with the kids, how/why would she spend too much time surfing the web?

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect.  To date, she has not spent any time on the net.  We have yet to setup the computer for her, and are looking for way to restrict her access prior to going live.

Comment: Or you can set the system to automatically shutdown, using scheduler

Comment: If you can't trust a "Middle Aged" lady to not be online all day and neglect your children then you really do need a new sitter.  Personally I think she'll be rather insulted that you've put these "restrictions" in place and are treating her like a child.  You've said yourself she's done nothing wrong so why treat her as if she has?

Comment: I need peace of mind.  When it comes to children I prefer safe than sorry.  Thanks for getting off-topic though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Babysitting the babysitter? This is a _people problem_, and those are not best solved by _technical_ means. Do you trust your babysitter to not neglect your children in other situations? Do you have _any reason_ to believe she will misbehave with internet access? BTW, the previous post is not "off topic" as you said - __you don't solve people problems by technical means!__ To avoid further discussions on the "Babysitter problem" - don't frame it as part of your question. Just ask the technical question if you are not willing to take advice regarding the big picture.

Comment: What's interesting is that I didn't ASK for advice regarding the big picture, but everyone seems AWFULLY interested in GIVING non-solicited advice.  Off-topic and unhelpful.  Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: We understand that that is not the advice you're interested in. However, it is the advice you *should* receive when you ask advice on such a topic. You think you've already found your solution and just need a little help with the last step. But the solution you've picked is simply not a viable option. People even come here asking how to use [a bandsaw controller as a browser](http://superuser.com/questions/423061/is-there-a-modern-browser-that-runs-on-windows-3-1). If you trust her enough with your child, you should trust her enough with your internet!

Comment: You used the word "should".  What should or should not be done is subjective.  Case in point, you should stop imposing your values on other people.  "If you trust her enough with your child, you should trust her enough with your internet!"  Oliver, no one asked you for your parenting advice but you certainly seem very interested in giving it.  Off-topic, unsolicited, and unhelpful.  This thread is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at something like [Net Nanny](http://www.netnanny.com)?
[image: Time management]

Comment: I checked it out, doesn't have what I described.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I wouldnt bother.  If she cant use your computer, she will just use her phone.

If you really want to do this, some routers have built in family controls to enable and disable access to the internet.  Also, depending on your OS, there are many built in parental controls.

There are also 3rd party software programs that can limit access.  I know the top ones are paid, but Im sure there are free ones as well.

Comment: Actually your assumptions are incorrect.  She is a middle-aged lady who does not have a smartphone with internet.  She relies on a desktop to get internet.  Also, our router has time-based restrictions meaning I can restrict internet to certain parts of the day (e.g. no internet from 12pm-3pm) but that does not give us the flexibility we desire.  We are okay with her using internet whenever all of the children are sound asleep, whenever that may be.  Can you give me any examples of 3rd party software that addresses my situation?  Thanks.

Comment: @phan How would the software know when your kids are asleep?

Comment: @Louis.  I think you misunderstand.  We leave it to the sitter to go online when the kids are all asleep.  In that scenario, she could surf for X minutes.  Then, when the session ends, she cannot go back online until Y minutes elapses.  The software does not know when the kids are asleep.  I think you're getting way ahead of yourself here.  I really am just looking for controls that will allow me to do what I described above in the question.  Thanks.